# Remove "Server:" from response headers in Apache server

Tags: apache-http-server

I am trying to remove "Server:" Header from Apache response headers. I found a lot of tutorials there but all of them shows how to hide version information from "Server" header.

So far I tried:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens ProductOnly
```

But it still outputs "Server: Apache" in response headers.

Is there any way I can completely turn this header off?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod_headers`, configure with (second is for error conditions like `not found`):

```
Header unset Server
Header always unset Server
```

Comment: This isn't removing sever from header.

Comment: Seems that Apache decided to force the Server header regardless of that configuration.